# Combine two "dbl" columns in a dataframe into a new column with unite()::tidyr return "chr"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I am working with **flights data** from **nycflights13 package** in **R**.

I tried to convert *dep_time* and *sched_dep_time* column to convert them to a more convenient representation of time. This should be simple, but I am struggling with it.

First I used Modular arithmetic and remainder inside the **transmute::dplyr** to break integers (dep_time and sched_dep_time) up into pieces  than used **unite::tidyr** . Like this:

```
flights %>% 
  transmute(dep_time,
          hour = dep_time %/% 100,
          minute = dep_time %% 100,
          sched_dep_time,
          hour2 = sched_dep_time %/% 100,
          minute2 = sched_dep_time %% 100)%>%
          unite(New_dep_time , hour,minute , sep =":") %>%
          unite(New_sched_dep_time , hour2,minute2 , sep =":")
```

My code returning result like this (return news columns *New_dep_time* and and *New_sched_dep* as chr):

```
# A tibble: 336,776 x 4
   dep_time New_dep_time sched_dep_time New_sched_dep_time
 *    <int>        <chr>          <int>              <chr>
 1      517         5:17            515               5:15
 2      533         5:33            529               5:29
 3      542         5:42            540               5:40
 4      544         5:44            545               5:45
 5      554         5:54            600                6:0
 6      554         5:54            558               5:58
 7      555         5:55            600                6:0
 8      557         5:57            600                6:0
 9      557         5:57            600                6:0
10      558         5:58            600                6:0
# ... with 336,766 more rows
```

I am wondering why unite function paste together two "dbl" columns (ex: *hour and minute*) into one column as "chr" (*New_dep_time*). Is there any way to implement *hm()* from *lubridate* inside unite to return *New_dep_time* and and *New_sched_dep* column as a **time format**?

Comment: You can add a `mutate` at the end to define the time format.

Comment: "time" is `POSIXct`. `hm()` produces a `Period` object. That's an important distinction. Deltas will work (if you're going to to that) but will likely not behave as you're expecting in all circumstances.